# How do I get scrape data from web pages using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape the data from the given link bellow,
[a link](https://www.imdb.com/chart/top)

And I an saving it into csv file.

I got all movies name, but in other format bellow, please see bellow:
I am getting bellow format in csv:

```
T h e " " S h a w s h a n k " " R e d e m p t i o n

T h e " " G o d f a t h e r

T h e " " G o d f a t h e r : " " P a r t " " I I

T h e " " D a r k " " K n i g h t

1 2 " " A n g r y " " M e n

S c h i n d l e r ' s " " L i s t
```

It should be:

```
The Shawshank Redemption

The Godfather

The God father: Part II

The Dark Knight
```

I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
movie = soup.find_all(class_='titleColumn')

for names in movie:
    for name in names.find_all('a'):
        movies=list(name.text)
        # print(movies)

        # IN CSV
        with open('TopMovies.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter = ' ')
            writer.writerow(movies)
        csvFile.close()
        print(movies)

print("Successfully inserted")
```

Please, Let me know if its any changes in my code.

Thanks

Comment: just replace `movies=list(name.text)` with `movies = name.text`, will get your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in line `movies=list(name.text)` - you are creating list, where each item is character from the string `name.text`.

Instead of this `list()`, you can use list-comprehension `movies = [name.text for name in names.find_all('a')]`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
movie = soup.find_all(class_='titleColumn')

for names in movie:
    movies = [name.text for name in names.find_all('a')]
    # print(movies)

    # IN CSV
    with open('TopMovies.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter = ' ')
        writer.writerow(movies)
    csvFile.close()
    print(movies)

print("Successfully inserted")
```

This will create `TopMovies.csv` correctly.

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]